# How do you get a value from a TextField in DataGridView while the field is being updated

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with text in there (i.e. `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`), and every time text changes in one of these fields, some update method has to be called somewhere else. However, I noticed that when you are updating a TextBox, the `Value` in the `Cell` is not updated yet.

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView m_DataGridView;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn m_textBoxColumn;

    private void m_DataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs editEvent)
    {
        if (editEvent.Control as TextBox != null)
        {
            TextBox textBox = editEvent.Control as TextBox;
            textBox.TextChanged -= new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
            textBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
        }
    }

    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateText();
    }

    private void UpdateText()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in m_DataGridView.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[1].Value != null)
            {
                string text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So to give an example: if the text in a TextBox is currently `"F"`, and you type `"oo"`, I would expect the console to output:

```
"F"
"Fo"
"Foo"
```

Instead, what it actually writes is:

```
"F"
"F"
"F"
```

Is there a way to access the contents of all TextBoxes from within the in `UpdateText()` method while the TextBoxes are being edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGridViewCell.Value` **won't** be updated right while you type in the `Editing control`. It's by design. The `Value` is updated after it's `Validated` when the `CurrentCell` is not in edit mode. I think you want something like this:

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateText(sender as Control);
}
private void UpdateText(Control editingControl)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(editingControl.Text);
}
```

### UPDATE

I think you can try some thing like this:

```
string editingText;
int editingRowIndex = -1;
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    editingRowIndex = ((DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)sender).EditingControlRowIndex;
    editingText = (sender as Control).Text;
    UpdateText();
}
private void UpdateText()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in m_DataGridView.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[1].Value != null)
        {
            string text = row.Index == editingRowIndex ?
                          editingText : row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, I didn't know that that was by design. However, while your solution would work for this example, would there be a way to keep `UpdateText()` parameterless? Because I am also calling this method at other times when the Control is not know.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! That works as a work-around for the problem. The only scenario were it doesn't work yet is in the very beginning, when the `row.Cells[1].Value` is `null` as long as you haven't finished editing the text. So I'll have to write another work-around for that. Do Windows Forms always involve so much hacking about? :(

Comment: @Yellow I don't think it's hacky. It's in fact how the `DataGridView` works, it's by design. If you customize the `DataGridView Editing control` yourself, you may be able to change that behavior.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess there are always design compromises to be made. The initial `null` problem was easily solved by the way, by adding to the constructor:
`foreach (DataGridViewRow row in m_DataGridView.Rows) { row.Cells[1].Value = ""; }`